# SQL CTE Does Not Return Sum

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I am trying to sum all invoice detail lines and return 1 row with the total amount using CTE. However, the CTE below is simply returning one of the invoice lines. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
with getinvoices as
(
    select 
        i.invoice_nbr,
        i.invoice_type_id,
        i.invoice_type_desc,
        i.invoice_total_amount,
        row_number() over (partition by i.invoice_nbr order by i.rowid) rn,
        sum(i.line_amount) as "Sum Of Line Amount"
    from
        ods_dev.invoices i
    where
        i.invoice_date >= '7/1/2020' 
        and i.invoice_date < '7/2/2020'
        and i.invoice_nbr is not null
    group by
        i.invoice_nbr, i.invoice_type_id, 
        i.invoice_type_desc, i.invoice_total_amount, i.rowid
)
select *
from getinvoices g
where g.rn = 1
order by g.invoice_nbr
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `row_number()`?  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you just want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT i.invoice_nbr, i.invoice_type_id, i.invoice_type_desc, i.invoice_total_amount,
       SUM(i.line_amount) as "Sum Of Line Amount"
FROM ods_dev.invoices i
WHERE i.invoice_date >= '2020-07-01' and i.invoice_date < '2020-07-02' and
      i.invoice_nbr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.invoice_nbr, i.invoice_type_id, i.invoice_type_desc, i.invoice_total_amount
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that does return the correct total. If there a way to accomplish it with a CTE? I may need to grab a specific line out of each set if there is a particular detail to look at in each partition, but I still need the sum of all lines. I may need to use a different Windows Function.

Comment: @WinstonSnyder . . . You can wrap just about any query in a CTE.